# ng-mouseenter fires first time, string is not a function next

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code on my html page:

```
<span data-miid="{{ orden._id }}"
      data-fetxa="{{orden.fetxa}}"
      data-linea="1"
      ng-mouseenter="arraton(orden.ref);"
      ng-click="grafikoa(orden.ref);"
      ng-if="isadmin"
      ng-bind-html="orden.ref"
      >{{orden.ref}}</span>
```

And this is the angular part:

```
$scope.arraton = function(val) {
        if ( ( val === "" ) || ( val === undefined ) ) { return false; }
        var of="";
        val = val.replace("<BR>", "<br>");
        val = val.replace("<BR />", "<br>");
        val = val.replace("<br />", "<br>");
        if (val === undefined) {
            return false
        }
        var n = val.indexOf("<br>");
        if (n > 0) {
            var miarray = val.split('<br>');
            of = miarray[1];
        }
        var url = "SOMEURL/delaoferta?of="+of;
        $http.get(url)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.arraton = "A Frabricar: " + parseInt(data.QFabricar) 
                            + "<br />Iniciada: " + parseInt(data.QIniciada) 
                            + "<br />Fabricada: " + parseInt(data.QFabricada);
        })
        .error(function () {
            console.log("error al obtener datos");
            return;
        });
    }
```

The fact is that when I mouse over the span, the first time works fine, but then, I´m getting

```
TypeError: string is not a function
```

all the time a mouse over the span.

Any help or clue?
thx

Comment: You can replace all those `<BR /> <br />` to `<br>` using regex and reducing your code `val = val.replace(/(<br\ ?\/?>)/gi, "<br>");` also note that `replace` can be chained as returning a string.

Comment: and for your issue in cases where `val` is undefined then `val.replace` would surely fail as `undefined` doesn't have any methods! Make sure `val` is defined prior using `replace`. Just move your if condition higher, the replace will not make it undefined.

Comment: I updated my code on the function to be sure that val have a value. Still same error, String is not a funcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the success of yout $http request, your setting an string when your ng-mouseenter need a function. Change a variable name and you are done.